# How can I add another array to this code? I tried giving a semicolon(;) but it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, html

```
{
    "users":[
            {
               "tab":"Tab1"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Tab2"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Tab3"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Tab4"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Tab5"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Username"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Password"
            },
            {
               "tab":"State"
            },
            {
               "tab":"Country"
            }
    ]
}
```

How can I add another array to this code? I tried adding a semicolon(;) but that does not work.

Comment: `obj.newarray = [];`?

Comment: This question is a little more than totally unclear. Can it be the unclearest question of the day?

Comment: i just want to add another array with another name...can any1 help..??

Comment: @liza: `var anotherArray = [];`  That's another array.  What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: you have to say how are you going to use the array you are asking to add, and maybe knowing that someone will be able to help you

Comment: Damnit. I wrote eleaborate answer and while writing it, question was put on hold and now I have useless answer that I can't submit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but your first key is "users" and the value is an array full of objects. To add a second key with an array value separate them with a comma. [This site](http://jsonlint.com/) is useful for json validation.

```
{"users":[
    {
       "tab":"Tab1"
    },
    {
       "tab":"Tab2"
    },
    {
       "tab":"Tab3"
    },
    {
        "tab":"Tab4"
    },
    {
       "tab":"Username"
    },
    {
       "tab":"Password"
    },
    {
       "tab":"State"
    },
    {
       "tab":"Country"
    }], 
"something else": [{
       "tab":"Tab1"
    },
    {
       "tab":"Tab2"
    }]
}
```